# SQL joining on 2 separate date columns

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-modeling

I am having trouble wrapping my head around a problem and the more I think about it the further away I get.

I have two tables that log user visits into two separate applications. For simplicities sake, let's say there are only 2 columns, timestamp and userid (key). Each row counts as a visit, so technically 3 columns since there is one derived for visits.

I am trying to create a table that in each row records the userid, the day (to_date format), total visits to app 1 and total visits to app 2 for that user on that day.

The issue is, when I join the tables together on userid and date, I get missing data. For example, if a user logged into application A on day X, but did not log into application B on day X, then joining on userid and day causes this record to be omitted since the date only exists in Application A's table.

How can I set this up where the final table would have a singular date column, userid, visits to app A and visits to app B, regardless if the user visited both applications on said day?

Hope this made sense, happy to elaborate if needed. Below is sort of what my SQL looks like as of now. Any thoughts appreciated!

```
with app_a_visits as (
      select to_date(timestamp) as date, userid, count(*) as visits
      from app_a),

app_b_visits as (
  select to_date(timestamp) as date, userid, count(*) as visits
  from app_b)

select a.date, a.userid, a.visits as app_a_visits, b.visits as app_b_visits
from app_a_visits a
full outer join app_b_visits b on a.userid = b.user_id and a.date = b.date;
```

Comment: Why does it needs a join, if you only need total from two tables? As I understand both are separate events, so cant you just count and group-by and union both table sets.

Answer (score 2):

Use FULL OUTER JOIN and NVL/COALESCE

```
with app_a_visits(date, userid,visits) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-01-01'::date, 1, 100),
    ('2022-01-03'::date, 1, 100),
    ('2022-01-05'::date, 1, 100)
), app_b_visits(date, userid,visits) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-01-02'::date, 1, 200),
    ('2022-01-03'::date, 1, 200),
    ('2022-01-04'::date, 1, 200)
)
select 
    NVL(a.date, b.date) as date,
    NVL(a.userid, b.userid) as userid,
    a.visits as app_a_visits, 
    b.visits as app_b_visits
from app_a_visits a
full outer join app_b_visits b 
    on a.userid = b.userid and a.date = b.date
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

| DATE | USERID | APP_A_VISITS | APP_B_VISITS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 100 | null |
| 2022-01-02 | 1 | null | 200 |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 | 100 | 200 |
| 2022-01-04 | 1 | null | 200 |
| 2022-01-05 | 1 | 100 | null |

Comment: Thanks Simeon - however I am still getting the same result set. Dates from app B where the user did not log into app A on said date are still missing.

Comment: Can you show some data in your questions and the expect results. Because a FULL OUTER JOIN is all rows..

Comment: Simeon - was not seeing expected values because of another filter - your solution worked, thank you!!